# datatable to string with unique rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a datatable and I want to create a text file using this datatable. I want that each row of the newly created text file is unique. If there is a duplicate row, then it should add * to both rows ( duplicate rows)

I am using following code:

```
 Dim str As String
            For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
                str += row(1)  ' This is text data            
                str += "<br/>"
            Next
```

Please suggest me how to make the rows unique.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to add `DISTINCT` records to your text file?  I'm a little unclear?

Comment: Could you please tell what is criteria to check rows? all the columns? single comment? string? etc etc

Comment: @KamranPervaiz and @@George: row(1)  should be unique

Comment: Did you try select distinct in your sql or this is not the option?

Comment: @KamranPervaiz datatable is created using XML and I dont want to use distint there ( even if possible) because I need to add * to the duplicate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my example I used an array with the data, but just replace the array part with your DataTable and you should be good to go.  Basically you build a List of strings with the DataTable information then use LINQ to check and see if that data already exists once, or more than once.

```
    Dim data As String() = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z"}
    Dim processedData = New List(Of String)
    Dim rowData = String.Empty
    Dim results = New StringBuilder()

    For Each row As String In data
        processedData.Add(row)
    Next

    For Each row As String In processedData
        rowData = row

        If (processedData.Where(Function(d) d = rowData).Count = 1) Then
            results.Append(rowData)
            results.Append("<br />")
        Else
            results.Append(rowData)
            results.Append("*")
            results.Append("<br />")
        End If

    Next
```

The results string is

```
A*<br />
B*<br />
C<br />
D<br />
E*<br />
A*<br />
E*<br />
F<br />
G<br />
H<br />
A*<br />
A*<br />
B*<br />
X<br />
Y<br />
Z<br />
```

Comment: Hi @Mike Thanks for the quick response. I used this code but it is adding * with the rows which dont have duplicate. Please suggest how to change it

Comment: It worked. I was getting * for the rows which were empty. One last thing, what If I want to show record numbers instead of * which are duplicate to each other ( by looking at the row(0) of datatable)

Comment: For the empty rows, you can do a couple things ... Either exclude them completely by wrapping the If statement inside the last loops with If (Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(rowData)) Then <code> or put the Ifs around the results.Append().

Comment: Which record numbers would you want to show?  All of the duplicates?  Can you show me a sample of what you'd want the output to look like?

Comment: in case of duplicates I want to show like this row(0) is  duplocate of row(0) where first row(0) is id of first row in duplication pair and second one is of second.

Comment: like this ***[_lCategoryKey_] is duplicate of [_lCategoryKey_]***